# python, juego de la ruleta

Tags: python

En el juego de la ruleta existen muchas formas de apostar, una de ellas es apostar al numero rojo o negro. Esta es una simulacion con probabilidades un numero aleatorio para dicha probailidad.
En mi tablero de ruleta existen los colores rojos, negros y verdes, a cada uno les asigne la probabilidad 0.45, 0.90, 1 respectivamente. si el # aleatorio cae en alguna de las probablidades. la cantidad apostada sube o decrementa en 1.
el jugador inicia con $50.
el juego termina cuando el jugador sume $250.
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
from random import random

i=1
cantIni=50
cantFin=250

print("CANT INI\tALEAT\tG/P\tCANT FIN")
while cantIni <=cantFin:
    aleatorio=random()
    if aleatorio<0.45:
        cantA=cantIni+1
        print("{}\t\t{}\tGANA\t{}".format(cantIni,str(aleatorio)[0:4],cantA))
    elif aleatorio<0.90:
        cantA=cantIni-1
        print("{}\t\t{}\tPIERDE\t{}".format(cantIni,str(aleatorio)[0:4],cantA))
    else:
        print("{}\t\t{}\t--\t{}".format(cantIni,str(aleatorio)[0:5],cantA))

    cantIni+=1
print("---------------------------------FIN-DEL-PROGRAMA-------------------------------")
```

la salida del programa se ve asi:

```
CANT INI        ALEAT   G/P     CANT FIN
50              0.72    PIERDE  49
51              0.12    GANA    52
52              0.41    GANA    53
53              0.61    PIERDE  52
54              0.30    GANA    55
55              0.95    --      55
56              0.23    GANA    57
57              0.51    PIERDE  56
58              0.28    GANA    59
59              0.20    GANA    60
60              0.76    PIERDE  59
61              0.05    GANA    62
62              0.86    PIERDE  61
63              0.86    PIERDE  62
64              0.46    PIERDE  63
65              0.10    GANA    66
66              0.89    PIERDE  65
67              0.01    GANA    68
68              0.91    --      68
69              0.40    GANA    70
70              0.68    PIERDE  69
71              0.45    PIERDE  70
72              0.23    GANA    73
73              0.71    PIERDE  72
74              0.88    PIERDE  73
75              0.26    GANA    76
-                 -        -     -
-                 -        -     -
-                 -        -     -
236             0.50    PIERDE  235
237             0.968   --      235
238             0.34    GANA    239
239             0.51    PIERDE  238
240             0.46    PIERDE  239
241             0.967   --      239
242             0.16    GANA    243
243             0.37    GANA    244
244             0.78    PIERDE  243
245             0.40    GANA    246
246             0.85    PIERDE  245
247             0.09    GANA    248
248             0.88    PIERDE  247
249             0.81    PIERDE  248
250             0.84    PIERDE  249
---------------------------------FIN-DEL-PROGRAMA-------------------------------
```

Tengo un errora partir de la sgunda iteracion, pues la cantidad inicial debe ser la cantidad final de la anterior y asi hasta que la cantidad final de x itercion llegue a 250, ejemplo:

```
CANT INI        ALEAT   G/P     CANT FIN
    50              0.72    PIERDE  49
    51              0.12    GANA    52
```

para la segunda iteracion, cantidad inicial deberia ser 49.

Agradesco las respuestas y comentarios.

Comment: `catnIni=cantA`, en vez de `cantIni+=1`

Comment: @abulafia gracias por tu respuesta, el programa ya no hace incremento de 1 si no que ahora toma la variable cantA. justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al cambiar la linea `cantIni+=1` por `catnIni=cantA`, el programa no hace incremento de 1, si no que pasa a ser la variable cantA.